# saving temp data

Tags: scheduled-tasks, tempdata

Sometimes we need to save some data temp within a transaction . and if it is
not compeleted, it will be deleted . for example, uploading images .

What is the best strategy for that ? saving data in the actual database and 
doing Task Scheduling that will delete incompelete data (row) or saving it
in temp space or what ?

Thanks a lot .

Comment: the best approach here may depend on platform / architecture - you might want to be more specific

Comment: @Marc: you have the patience of a saint! Guess that's just one of the reasons you're an admin! ;)

Comment: Any suggestions please .

Comment: @HTB: 4 hours after asking the question, all you can add is that you're using .NET? Very poor...

Answer (score 1):

Example for Temp data, i hope i'm doing it right. taking an example from busroute:-

```
  if (id != busRoute.BusRouteCode)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(busRoute);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!BusRouteExists(busRoute.BusRouteCode))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(busRoute);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("BusRouteCode,RouteName")] BusRoute busRoute)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(busRoute);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(busRoute);
    }
```

**For Index:-** 
          TempData["message"] = "Welcome to the Membership List...";

```
        if (MemberId == null)
        {
            TempData["message"] = "Please select a Member...";
            RedirectToAction("SHMember", "Index");
        }

        string memberId = MemberId.ToString();
        var FullName = _context.Membership
            .Include("FullName")
            .Where(m => m.MemberId == MemberId)
            .Select(m => m.Member.FullName)
            .FirstOrDefault(); 

        if (memberId != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("MemberId", memberId);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("FullName", FullName);
        }
        else
        {
            memberId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("MemberId");
            FullName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("FullName");

            if (memberId == null)
            {
                //return to View and Display Message
                TempData["message"] = "Please select a Member...";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Member");
            }
        }

        ViewBag.FullName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("FullName");

        var MembershipContext = _context.Membership
            .Where(m => m.MemberId == MemberId)
            .OrderByDescending(m=>m.Year);



        return View(await MembershipContext.ToListAsync());
```

Comment: Code only answers are really discouraged. To help future readers, please explain what you are doing too!